# обработать загрузку ImageView из URL в методе функции

Tags: kotlin, url, imageview, picasso

не знаю, как правильно будет обработать загрузку URL ImageView в функции loadPhotoIntoImageView не используя библиотки вроде Picasso. С Picasso все прекрасно работает.

```
class PhotosViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val imageViewPhoto: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPhoto)
        private val textViewTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle)

        fun bind(photo: Photo) {
            textViewTitle.text = photo.title
            loadPhotoIntoImageView(photo.url, imageViewPhoto)
        }

        private fun loadPhotoIntoImageView(url: String, imageView: ImageView) {
            //Picasso.get().load(url).into(imageViewPhoto)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Рекомендую не изобретать велосипед а воспользоваться какой то библиотекой.**

Если же загружать изображение вручную, то нужно это хотя бы в AsyncTask.

Дальше пойдет копипаст из [статьи на medium](https://medium.com/@crossphd/android-image-loading-from-a-string-url-6c8290b82c5e)

---

Внутри метода doInBackground в AsyncTask вам необходимо:

- Создать переменную Bitmap
- Откройте InputStream с URL-адресом, который был передан в AsyncTask
- Используйте BitmapFactory.decodeStream() в InputStream
- Присвоить его созданной переменной Bitmap.

Затем в методе onPostExecute просто используете setImageBitmap в объекте ImageView, чтобы добавить изображение, как вы можете видеть ниже.

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;
    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bmp;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

В результате в `loadPhotoIntoImageView` вы можете использовать след код

```
new DownloadImageTask(imageView).execute(url);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, знаю, что все используют в таких случаях AsyncTask, но у меня студия ругается. 
Вот думал, может кто-то уже создал велосипед на этот случай, а я о нем не знаю.

Comment: @Eliseyslode, ругается скорее всего потому что устарел, но альтернатива AsyncTask существует и это уже другой вопрос, смысл в том что бы в отдельном потоке грузить изображение и декодировать в Bitmap, а после в main потоке взаимодействовать с ImageView